# How can we output the results of a script to a csv file?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

So I have a simple script that I am using to extract some data from a file.
It is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in *; do 
    cat "$file" | grep "col1\|col2" | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr "\n" ",";
    echo; 
done
```

I want to output the results of this to a csv file. How do I do that?

Comment: Why doesn't this work if you redirect the output to a file?

Comment: Do you know how to do input and output redirection in shell?

Comment: No, I dont. I am new to this. How do I output the result to a file (instead of cat)?

Comment: You're looking for `... done >file.csv`.